# jQuery's val() method returns too few characters for keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, jquery-events

In my form I add one text box (`$("#seltxt")`) and one div having text inside. when I select the div text comes in a text box this works fine. Now I added function keypress in the `#seltxt` in key press event I am copying the textbox text to div. But it getting one less character.

Example:

div having text "manojgangwar" when I am clicking on div ,"manojgangwar" copies to `#seltxt`. Now suppose I write character "manojgangwar123" in textbox then in div it is only coming "manojgangwar12"

Below is the jQuery to capture `keypress` event:

```
 //function to set text to div

$("#seltxt").keypress( function(event) {
   $('#' + objid).text($("input#seltxt").val());
});
```

Comment: Can we get all the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keypress event is fired while a key is pressed, before the default behaviour has occurred. This allows scripts to cancel the default behaviour (e.g. populating an input field) through the `event.preventDefault()` method.

Use the `keyup` event, if you need an event which is fired when the input value has changed.

Also, since `$("input#selText")` points to itself, you can also use `$(this).val()` instead. A further optimisation would consist of using `this.value`, which is universally supported.

```
$("#seltxt").keyup( function(event) {
   $('#' + objid).text(this.value);
});
```

### A final note on key events

- `keydown` - Fired once, right after a key is pressed. Can be used to prevent the first default event.
- `keypress` - Fired possibly multiple times, while keys are pressed. Can be used to prevent default behaviour (`keydown` is fired only once, if you hold key pressed, the default behaviour would occur, unless you define a `keypress` event)
- `keyup` - Fired after the key is released. Using `event.preventDefault()` cannot prevent text from being modified by keyboard input.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: No, it won't.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The `keydown` event is fired before `keypress`, so the `keydown` event will certainly not work. See the final note in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much keyup worked for me and thanks for information regarding key events you shared.

Comment: @Rob W, thank you for adding the clarification notes that makes this a really nice answer and +1. I did not see any event.preventDefault() in the OP code.

Answer (score 1):

it's workin'...

```
$("#seltxt").live("keyup", function(event) {
   $('#' + objid).text($(this).val());
});
```